# Could not load file or assembly 'SOMEXYZ' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

Could not load file or assembly 'SOMEXYZ' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

This is the error I am getting when I am trying to load my WCF service after hosting.

Comment: Please provide the piece of code, where this error happens.

Comment: This error is coming in browser when I am running the wcf service in localhost.

Comment: this error is fixed. I just selected the advanced settings of my application pool in IIS which I created for my application. In the settings I selected Enable 32-bit applications to True. And the Service was hosted successfully in the browser. :) as my System is 64 bit.